# Wicked_PDF link to pdf for the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, wicked-pdf

I am working with Wicked_PDF to generate pdf files for my application. Most examples normally have it generating based on a show page, but I want a link to get to a pdf for an index page.

**Product Controller**

```
  def index
    @search = Product.search(params[:q])
    @products = @search.result.includes(:supplier, :prodcategory, :prodstatus)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf =>"product_report", :template => 'products/index.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

**Product Index**

```
<p><%= link_to "Printable Invoice (PDF)", products_path(@products, format:"pdf") %></p>
```

I know for certain that localhost:3000/products.pdf generates it just fine, but I'm having issues figuring out the correct path for the link.

Comment: Could you please expand a little on the problem? Is the `products_path()` helper you posted not working, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @Unixmonkey, sorry, to expand a bit -yes the current products_path() helper does not work. Just to clarify I want the link_to to open the generated pdf of the index.html.erb page for products, but I am unfamiliar with how to correctly write it. I should have prefaced this by saying I am generally new to rails.

Comment: I generated a scaffold for products in a Rails app I use with `bin/rails g scaffold product`, then pasted your code above into it, and it worked fine. However, I think for an index resource, you should omit the `@products` argument, and call like `products_path(format: "pdf")` or `products_path(format: :pdf)`, which also worked for me.

Comment: @Unixmonkey That worked fine, thank you! Truth be told, i had actually tried that exact solution earlier but I realize now that I probably should have restarted the server. Either way, thanks!